# Creating API project: Embed config file into dll

Tags: c#, .net, api

I am creating the API project which will be consumed by other tools. Now I have build the class library project which contains all logic and has some configuration placed in app.config file. Now when I build the project, I get the dll and config file. I want to embed the config file in DLL. How to do it?
Am I following it right? Or is there any other way to do it?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to embed the file in the dll, I assume you don't want the end user to have the ability to change the configuration after the dll is built?

I don't know what kind of info you read from the config file, but if the above is true, why not move the configuration data to a config class inside the dll?

Answer (score 0):

Just treat the config file as a Resource in dll and then read the resource file in runtime like:

```
var assembly = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();
var resourceName = "MyCompany.MyProduct.MyFile.txt";

using (Stream stream = assembly.GetManifestResourceStream(resourceName))
using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(stream))
{
    string result = reader.ReadToEnd();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

That's not necessary.
If you don't have a configfile than the default values are used.
In your consuming program you can overwrite them in the `.exe.config` or `Web.config` file.